# How to find $x+y$ of this?

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

$$|x.y| = -2x$$
$$|\frac{y}{x}| = 3y$$
So how do i find to $x+y$? I don't have any idea about the problem because it seems so hard to me. But I've tried a few ways to solve it and got $\frac{3}{2}$. I think I'm wrong.

Comment: What does $x.y$ mean here?  Is it $x$ times $y$?

Comment: Assume that $x,y$ have the same sign.  What possible solutions do you get?  Then assume that they have opposite signs.  Find a solution set.  Are the solutions you find consistent with the assumptions you have made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first one, you get
$$
|y| = \frac{-2x}{|x|},
$$
and since LHS is non-negative, we must have $x \le 0$, which yields $|y| = 2$.

From the second one,
$$
|x| = \frac{|y|}{3y},
$$ 
and since LHS is non-negative, $y \ge 0$, which implies $y=2$. That means, $x=-1/3$.

Comment: can you give more info? I didn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

The absolute values are non-negative, so $-2x\geq0$ and $3y\geq0$.
Apparently $x\neq0$ so that the second equation can make sense, so we get $x<0$ and $y\geq0$.
Knowing this, the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
xy&=&2x\\
-y/x&=&3y.
\end{cases}
$$
Can you now solve $y$ from the first equation?
After that you can get $x$ from the second one.